# AWS ELB & existing SSL Entrust certificate

Tags: ssl, amazon-ec2, amazon-elb

I have successfully installed a SSL certificate on my Windows box (2012 R2) and also added public keys & private keys to ELB. I have enabled https listeners on ELB, added 443 to security groups so that traffic isn't blocked.

But when I go to the site I notice it is throwing a 408. Am I missing something trying to convert http to https site? Are there any other steps involved that I may be missing?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do you have IGW in the subnet where you have your server?
Did you configure security groups in ELB or on the instance as well?

Comment: @Antoine I added that rule to EC2 security group (webservers SG) as well as ELB security group. Yes there is a internet gateway in the subnet.

Comment: Read one again and just noted that you have ssl in both places, on ELB and on EC2. Why not to leave SSL only on ELB to offload the instance?

Comment: @Antoine would that help in resolving the issue? I am really testing waters with this so not sure if offloading it to ELB & taking it out from EC2 will solve this? Also if I do offload, would that mean the https traffic will be forwarded to http on the server? Again just trying to understand everything as I test this.